# Elixir convert encoding EUC-KR(JP, CH)... to UTF-8

Tags: character-encoding, elixir

I'm making crawling app. I want to parse some characters.
But some pages are not UTF-8 charset.

I got page body and now I want to do some work with the body string. 
First of all, I should convert encoding to UTF-8 if the page encoding is not UTF-8.

How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Erlang iconv library](https://github.com/processone/iconv) to do such conversions. It's easy!

1. Make sure you have `iconv` installed on your system
2. Add `{:iconv, "~> 1.0.0"}` to deps and  `:iconv` to applications in `mix.exs`
3. Convert with `:iconv.convert("euc-kr", "utf-8", "input")`

You can find a [list of supported encodings on the libiconv page](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or by running `iconv --list` in the command line.